# ManyToMany relationship only lets add from one side Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, many-to-many, easyadmin

I'm a totally new Symfony user - I'm trying to make a ManyToMany relationship with User and Entity Group, however i can edit those only from one side(Group atm). Struggling with this for two days.. Would really appreciate some help. Here is my code..

**Group Entity:**

```
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=160)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Vartotojas::class, inversedBy="groups")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Vartotojas[]
     */
    public function getUsers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    public function addUser(Vartotojas $user): self
    {
        if (!$this->users->contains($user)) {
            $this->users[] = $user;
            $user->addGroup($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

**User Entity:**

```
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Grupe::class, inversedBy="users")
     */
    private $groups;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Grupe[]
     */
    public function getGroups(): Collection
    {
        return $this->groups;
    }

    public function addGroup(Grupe $group): self
    {
        if (!$this->group->contains($group)) {
            $this->groups[] = $group;
            $group->addUser($this);
            
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

I'm using EasyAdmin to manage those, and my Group/User crud's are the same like this:

```
namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Grupe;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\AssociationField;

class GrupeCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Grupe::class;
    }

    
    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            TextField::new('name'),
            AssociationField::new('users'),
        ];
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to edit a user inside the Group admin, I think what you are looking for is the CollectionField, this works with a Symfony form created by you.